# Scrollbar appears through CSS animation/transition

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am animating my ng-view in Angular with a **cubic-bezier** transition:

```
/* Animations */
.slide-animation.ng-enter, .slide-animation.ng-leave  {
  -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
  -moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
  -o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;

  position:absolute;
}

.slide-animation.ng-enter {
  opacity:0;
  left:300px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

.slide-animation.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.slide-animation.ng-leave {
  opacity:0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.slide-animation.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity:0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Everything works fine, **except of the scrollbar which appears when the content is entering.** It moves from the right to the left side (as you can see in the code).

> I want to hide the scrollbar during the animation.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: html, body { overflow: hidden} ?

Comment: but then there is no scrollbar EVER... i want to scroll my content.

Comment: ok, set overflow auto after the animation or try using css clip... a little bit difficult help you without the rest of the html-page, css,...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to set `overflow:hidden` in the `body` css. But note that, adding this will hide all overflown contents including the vertical scroll bar and you dont want to do that since the page contents will be hidden if the height is overflown. So if you are using a slide transition (sidewards) and you only want to hide the horizontal scroll bar that appears during transition, then use this instead:

```
 body {
    overflow-x:hidden;  
}
```

This way, you are only hiding the horizontal scroll bar and the vertical scroll bar will still work.

Comment: I had the same problem but setting `overflow-x:hidden;` in the body removed my vertical scrolling as well. Why?

Comment: `overflow-x:hidden;` will not remove the vertical scrolling. Could there be another property in your body css overriding this? If yes, you can manually override it by adding `overflow-y:scroll;` to show the vertical scrolling.

Comment: I don't know why this is an accepted answer but `overflow-x:hidden`; will not remove the vertical scrolling as @Neel said

Answer (score 1):

Two alternative to solve the flickering problem (movement left/right that happens with scrollbars appearing/disappearing fast)

**display scrollbars all the time**.

```
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**This hack** ([info](https://css-tricks.com/elegant-fix-jumping-scrollbar-issue/))

```
html { 
  margin-left: calc(100vw - 100%); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. This is how I solved it (I'm using my own code as an example)

**HTML**

```
<div class="team-box-2-info">
    <h4>John Doe</h4>
    <h6>Programmer</h6>
    <p class="team-box-2-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetum...</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.team-box-2-desc {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
}
.team-box-2:hover .team-box-2-desc{
    max-height: 350px;
    transition: max-height 1s ease-in;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.team-box-2').hover(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        element.find('p.team-box-2-desc').css('overflow-y', 'auto');
    }, 1000);
}, function(){
    $(this).find('p.team-box-2-desc').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution here to hide scrollbar temporary during transition animation using keyframes
https://css-tricks.com/hide-scrollbars-during-an-animation/

Answer (score 0):

A simple hack I do is create a keyframe, that has a longer duration than the animation and add it to the Html as an animation;

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
  max-width: 100%; /* n/a
  overflow-x: hidden;
  animation: hide-scroll 3s; /*my longest animation is 2.7s */
}

@keyframes hide-scroll {
  from,
  to {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

This method helps if you want the scrollbar showing on other pages. - you can create a fade-in etc. play around with the animation keyframes to your liking.