# Horizontal animation causes vertical scrollbar in css

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations

I am working on the website animation (a spinning cog and a text that infinitely moves left-right). Here is my body code

```
body {
overflow:hidden;
height:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
//background attachments
}
```

And here is a relevant animation code snippet from the same file

```
#cog { /* image on maintenance.html page */
display:block;
margin:auto;
margin-top:300px;
animation:spin 5s ease infinite;
}
@keyframes spin { /* animation for image on maintenance.html page */
from { transform:rotate(-45deg); }
50% { transform:rotate(10deg); }
75% { transform:rotate(-10); }
to { transform:rotate(-45deg); }
}
#maintenance { /* text image under cog graphic on maintenance.html page */
display:block;
margin:auto;
/* margin-top:30px; */
animation:maint 5s ease infinite;
overflow: hidden;
}
@keyframes maint { /* animation for second image on maintenance.html page */
50% { transform: translate(-200px, 0); }
}
```

When the text reaches its final point to the right (or really close to it), it causes a vertical scrollbar to appear. And the closer the text gets to the right, the bigger the scrollbar becomes (the bar inside the scrollbar becomes smaller). And vice versa when text start moving from final right point to the left.

I have already checked [SO post on the similar matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973870/scrollbar-appears-through-css-animation-transition), [the article](https://css-tricks.com/findingfixing-unintended-body-overflow/), [and another article](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/code-css3-flip-animation-gives-me-a-horizontal-scrollbar/). All of them are suggesting to do an overflow:hidden, but it did not work for me: I tried both body and the text animation itself.

I also noticed that this scrollbar appears ONLY when the mouse is inside the animation container (not just idle mouse, but moving around).

It occurs on both of my different-size monitors, and I am using Google Chrome to test it.

## UPDATE

After trying suggested codepen and fiddle, it looks like a container with a navbar is at fault. I will play around with it and share the results.

## UPDATE 2

Resolved my issue, see the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will do the trick, but try adding position: relative to each element that's involved in the overflow. They default to static which might be what's causing your issue.

Comment: @will Just tried it - it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Any way you can post a working sample?

Comment: You mean html file?

Comment: Like a codepen http://codepen.io/pen/ or link to the site so I can actually look at it in action instead of having to replicate it

Comment: Same here; been working on a fiddle, but I can't seem to duplicate the problem. So can you post, preferably, a stacksnippet right here in the question that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @will Looks like div with navbar is at fault. I will notify about results, but I cannot share more than I can, sorry.

Comment: @MrLister Seems like container with navbar is at fault. Cannot share more than that, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying `overflow:hidden` to just body is not enough. That line is also needs to be applied to the container (with navbar in my case), which is present on the page, but not directly involved in the animation container.

The usage of [codepen](http://codepen.io/pen/) and [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) tools helped me to resolve my problem.

Hopefully my answer and these tools will help web-designers to resolve such problems in the future.